# Extend express res.json function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering how to extend the `res.json` function. I want it to do some string replacements before doing its normal duty.

My idea is to use that for translations

```
{
value:'some key'
}
```

and it comes out

```
{ 
value:'translated text'
}
```

any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a middleware that will replace `res.json()` with a function of your own:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let json = res.json.bind(res);
  res.json = (data) => {
    let newData = ...perform replacements here...
    return json(newData); // call the original `res.json()`, stored as `json`
  };
  next();
});
```